# Need to change connection string on client computer at run time

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please see the pic. and advise how I can change this connection string at run time.  This is going to be on Client's computer and my application will need to change the name of computer after user enters it.
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just on the top of my head..

```
Dim adapter As New dbTestSharingDataSet.tblTestTableAdapter
Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = MyConnectionManager.ConnectionString
adapter.Connection = conn
Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData()
```

Comment: So I do it like Dim conn As New SqlConnection()="Data Source=MyServer\SQLExpress....."

Comment: Basically, you could change the part conn.ConnectionString = "YourOwnConnectionString" on your preference.

Comment: So I donot put conn.ConnectionString = MyConnectionManager.ConnectionString but put conn.ConnectionString = "YourOwnConnectionString ?

Comment: You need to put in the connection string you have to connect to your DB. Your question asks how you can modify the connection string through code (runtime) and I cannot know what your connection string would look like.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I know what connection string to put.  I was just asking the place where to put.  Please advise if anything to import at top because there is an error on the first line you gave Dim adapter As New dbTestSharingDataSet.tblTestTableAdapter